# How to add a number char "01" with a number in php?

Tags: php

The code is just like below

```
$number = "03";
$num = substr($number, 1,2);
$number2 = 5;
$numtot = $num + $number2;
echo $numtot;   // Result 8

$numtot2 = str_pad($numtot, 2,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo "\n".$numtot2;   //  Result 08
```

But when `$number` is more or same than `10` like below the result will like below.

```
$number = "11";  // or $number = "21";
$num = substr($number, 1,2);
$number2 = 5;
$numtot = $num + $number2;
echo $numtot;   // Result 6

$numtot2 = str_pad($numtot, 2,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo "\n".$numtot2;   //  Result 06
```

How do i solved this ? what i expect from above code is the result should be `16` or `25`

And also is there a way so we didnt have to `str_pad` again after sum it ?
so just like simply, `03 + 5 = 08` and `09 + 7 = 16` or like `03 + 4 = 07`

Comment: As i understood your aim is to remove 0 from 03 then use it right ?

Comment: just add it, you don't need to do anything, php will do it for you `$numtot=$number+$number2;`

Comment: If you're gonna use PHP, you should read up on [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use php [intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function

```
$num = intval($number);
// instead
// $num = substr($number, 1,2);
```

**-- Update --**

```
$number = "11"; 
$num = intval($number);
$number2 = 5;
$numtot = $num + $number2;
echo $numtot; // 16
```

or evan lighter as **maxhb** was suggesting in a comment

```
$number = "11";
$number2 = 5;
$numtot = $num + $number2;
echo $numtot; // 16
```

Comment: You could even use PHPs internal type conversion to simply do `$numtot = $number + $number2;`. PHP will automatically try to cast your string to an integer value as soon as you try to add it.

Comment: @Armen i have edited my question, do you know how to solved that ?

Comment: @Gagantous look to the answer again i updated it with exact code. no need to use `str_pad` at all

Comment: but what if `03` and `5` , will the result `08` ?

Comment: @Gagantous it want as result is integer, you can try above code with your 03 and 5 numbers

Comment: @Gagantous - No, it won't. When you do addition like that, it will automatically cast the string "03" to 3, so "03" + 5 is equal to 3 + 5.

Comment: @Gagantous `echo str_pad($numtot, 2, 0,STR_PAD_LEFT);``

Comment: @Armen - In general I agree, but if you have a specific case where you know that the string looks like that, there's nothing wrong using PHP's type juggling. It is a language feature after all.

Comment: @splash58 is there any different way to do it without using `str_pad` ?

Comment: @Gagantous only make string, with it it's imposible